# Jenkins Pipeline scrip query

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am writing a Jenkins pipeline and having trouble comparing two variables within an if statement. I have a string value in the variable `Deploy_Version` and the value from a MySql query in the variable `git_branch` obtained using a SH script. Although I am able to print out their values and see that they are the same, when I try to compare them in my if statement, the comparison doesn't seem to work. Can someone take a look and help me identify what is going wrong?

Below is my test pipeline script:

```
properties([
    parameters([
        choice(choices: ['', 'dev-nccf.ifelsesolutions.in', 'qa-nccf.ifelsesolutions.in', 'uat-transfer'],
        description: 'Select build from drop box...', name: 'Select_Build'),
        string(defaultValue: '', 
        description: 'mention git branch version for deploying dev', name: 'Deploy_Version', trim: false),
        ])
        ])
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.Utils

environment {
    git_branch
}

node {
    stage('code checkout') {
        if (Select_Build == 'dev-nccf.ifelsesolutions.in' & Deploy_Version != ''){
            git branch: '${Deploy_Version}', credentialsId: 'git_if_else', url: 'https://github.com/If-Else-Solutions/${JOB_NAME}.git'
        }
        else if (Select_Build == 'qa-nccf.ifelsesolutions.in' & Deploy_Version != ''){
            script {
                git_branch = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'mysql -sN -h 1.1.1.1 -u user -ppassword nccf -e "SELECT Version FROM nccf.CI_CD_Version where deployment=\'qf\'"')
                echo " sql Output: ${git_branch}, Deploy_Version: ${Deploy_Version}, Globel: ${git_branch}"
                echo "condition start Output: ${git_branch}, Deploy_Version: ${Deploy_Version}, Globel: ${git_branch}"
                if (Deploy_Version == git_branch) {
                    println(git_branch)
                    println(Deploy_Version)
                    echo " if Output: ${git_branch}, Deploy_Version: ${Deploy_Version}, Globel: ${git_branch}, branch variable: ${git_branch}"
                    git branch: '${Deploy_Version}', credentialsId: 'git_if_else', url: 'https://github.com/If-Else-Solutions/${JOB_NAME}.git'
                }
                else {
                    println(git_branch)
                    echo " else Output: ${git_branch}, Deploy_Version: ${Deploy_Version}, Globel: ${git_branch}, branch variable: ${git_branch}"
                    Utils.markStageSkippedForConditional('code checkout')
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            Utils.markStageSkippedForConditional('code checkout')
        }
    }

    stage('variable check') {
        echo " variable check Output: ${git_branch}, Deploy_Version: ${Deploy_Version}, Global: ${git_branch}, branch variable: ${git_branch}"
    }
}
```